# Script para desabilitar e habilitar compos com "READONLY" a prtir de um Checkbox

Tags: javascript

Preciso de um script que abilite e desbilite um campo com READONLY a partir de um checkbox
Não sei programar em javascript, Como faço esse script

```
    <input readonly="" type="text" name="xx" value=""
    <input readonly="" type="text" name="xx" value=""
    <input readonly="" type="text" name="xx" value="" 
    Editar:<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="sim" />
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar Dados" /></p>
```

Então se marcardo o checkbox libera todos os campo para edição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

**Exemplo:**

```js
var editar = document.getElementById("editar");


// No click verifico se o editar esta marcado e desativo os 
// readOnly dos inputs type text
editar.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    toggleReadOnly(false);
  } else {
    toggleReadOnly(true);
  }
});

// Percorro  os elementos inputs type text e habilito/desabilito
function toggleReadOnly(bool) {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === "text") {
      inputs[i].readOnly = bool;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=text]:-moz-read-only {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
input[type=text]:read-only {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<input readonly="" type="text" name="xx" value="">
<input readonly="" type="text" name="xx" value="">
<input readonly="" type="text" name="xx" value="">
<label for="editar">Editar:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="sim" id="editar" />
<input type="submit" value="Salvar Dados" />
```

Comment: Perfeito... isso mesmo,... só um detalhe??? quando habilitado, o fundo poderia ficar com uma cor diferentes o pra mostra que o campo esta habilitado para edição. isso e complicado?

Comment: Você pode criar uma classe de css com essa cor de fundo e adicionar no input habilitado adicionando `inputs[i].className += " nomeDaMinhaClasse";` Porem por questões de UX não aconselho modificar o background do campo por ele ser padrão, você poderia apenas sobrescrever o css do readonly para deixar ele com uma aparência de disabled.

Comment: Show só tem um probleminha esse <form esta em um lightbox se eu desabilito o checkbox ele desabilita os campos que estão na pagina em baixo do lightbox, acho que esses campos teriam que  ser idetificado por um id

Comment: O problema proposto a ser resolvido é o do exemplo na sua pergunta acima, se você não o detalhou corretamente edite para que se encaixe no seu problema. Respondendo sua pergunta, você tem alguma dificuldade em remover o for e colocar fixo cada id  e setar o readonly? é a mesma lógica só que fixa

Comment: Não detalhei porque não sabia que o script que vai dentro do lightbox iria interferir na pagina mãe. a logica eu entendi eu não sei como troco o comando para percorre por id

Comment: @FabioHenrique pode fazer desse jeito: https://jsfiddle.net/o76ag8y8/

Comment: Perfeito agora obrigado

Comment: @FabioHenrique não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta caso ela tenha conseguido resolver o problema.